# Young adult science fiction book: everyone had telepathy, time travel through rift

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title of a book I read when I was in middle school. I read it in the late 1980's. Space travel was around and I remember vaguely that movement through time was also possible due to a some kind of rift. Everyone had telepathy, but a rare few had other powers like teleportation and telekinesis. the protagonist had a bunch of different powers like teleportation and precognition and telekinesis. Communication in space was done by telepathy.

One of the eras they visited was a world where everyone had telekinesis and didn't talk with telepathy.

Can anyone tell me the title of this book and the author?

Comment: Sounds interesting hope we find out what it is :) you may like Julian May's "The Saga of Pliocene Exile" / "The Galactic Milieu Series"

Answer (score 5):

Per Dreamwalker's comment, this fits strongly with the "[Saga of the Exiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile)" arc of the [Galactic Mileu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Milieu_Series) book series.

- *Late 80's* - **Check**.
  The first book was written in 1987 and followed by sequels in 1991, 1994 and 1997.
- *Space travel was around* - **Check**
  Several of the main characters are space-capable aliens representing races called the Tanu and the Firvulag. There are also repeated mentions of other races such as the [Poltroy, Krondaku and the Lylmik.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Milieu_Series#Alien_races)
- *Everyone had telepathy* - **Check**
  Almost all of the main characters have strong telepathic powers, unlocked by an electronic 'torc' worn around the throat.
- *A rare few had other powers like teleportation and telekinesis* - **Check**
  Only the three most powerful characters (Brede, Felice and Marc) are able to use their powers to D-Jump physically through space.
- *Movement through time was also possible due to a some kind of rift.* - **Check**
  The main thrust of the story was that a group of "exiles" had used a time machine to travel to the Pliocene epoch, a time before humans existed.

Comment: It isn't this one. I'm pretty sure that the book was fairly old when I read it, in hindsight. The book (I'm fairly certain it's not part of a series) is based on one race of people, and the time traveling is into the future, where the people have changed in strange ways. Like the telekinesis and people don't use telepathy anymore.

Comment: I didn't put this as answer as something didn't ring true to me.  But was worth mentioning to the OP as they might like it :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is the [*Warlock of Gramarye*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warlock_in_Spite_of_Himself#Sequels_and_spinoffs) series by Christopher Stasheff. It's got your space traveling protagonist, a planet full of telepaths, telekinetics, and other mental powers (mistaken for witchcraft), 2 factions of time traveling "history meddlers", if you will, and the protagonist eventually discovers his own extensive powers. One of the major themes was the conflict over the development of telepathy to the point where it would replace other forms of interstellar comms.

Comment: Not this one either, I loved that series, but it's a adult sci-fi and the book I'm after is YA. Thanks